# 'click' event with 'addEventListener' in javascript doesn't support holding the mouse

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In javascript, I am making a flappy bird-like game using the mouse to control the 'bird'. However, I have ran into an issue: whenever I hold the mouse, the bird drops down instead of going up. this is my code so far:

```
function handleMouseInput() {
    if (running === true) {
        box.changeY -= 0.56;
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseInput);
```

Is there a different option that supports my game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to push the bird up until the mouse is released. I'm not sure how your game works exactly, but I would imagine something like this:

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
// runs every game tick
function gameTick() {
    if(mouseIsDown) {
        /// push the bird up
        pushTheBirdUp();
    }
    else {
        /// bird goes down as usual
        pushTheBirdDown();
    }
    // render the game
    renderGame()
}

// now mouse handlers
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    mouseIsDown = true;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    mouseIsDown = false;
});
// mouse leaves the browser tab
window.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    mouseIsDown = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!